# Rails multiple facebook like buttons. Redirected link meta tags problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having that problem that I got some items on a list that needs a like button. 
That means I got multiple items on a page. I want to show an unique image and text when a user press like. The problem is that facebook meta tags goes in the header and it is only for the page. That means that the facebook like images are the same for all items. I have read this guide http://hillarsaare.com/multiple-facebook-like-buttons-on-one-page/ how to create multiple facebook likes with unique images and links. But my link that the user likes is a link that is been redirected in my controller to an external URL without any view.

Where should I place the meta tags? Should I create an view for my link ? How should I make an delay on the link that is been redirected?

Comment: I think I have an solution need just to test it on a webserver. Because facebook cant access my local files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a show file for my link. And but the facebook meta tags in the header, and some javascript to make the redirecet to my external link. In that way I can have multiple like buttons on a page with unique like information and images.